# Google places API for android showing statusCode=ERROR_OPERATION_FAILED

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, google-places-api

I am using [this](http://www.truiton.com/2015/04/android-places-api-autocomplete-getplacebyid/) tutorial to create a autocomplete search box. I have created a custom adapter to populate my autocomplete text box. the following code should give me autocomplete suggestions.

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                  .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                  .enableAutoManage(this, GOOGLE_API_CLIENT_ID, this)                
                  .addConnectionCallbacks(this)                
                  .build();

PendingResult<AutocompletePredictionBuffer> results =
            Places.GeoDataApi.getAutocompletePredictions(mGoogleApiClient,
                                                        constraint.toString(), 
                                                        mBounds, null);
```

unfortunately this gives me an error:

```
{statusCode=ERROR_OPERATION_FAILED, resolution=null}
```

I checked the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/search#PlaceSearchStatusCodes), there are no reference of ERROR_OPERATION_FAILED error.

There are no problems with my API key I guess, because I had another application with a working API key. I used the working API key in this application, still it is not working.

I tried turning off mobile data. Surprisingly the error is still there. The error comes instantly as I type (i.e. It looks like its not even going to the google service at all).

what could be the reason of this error?

Comment: Not sure but I think `ERROR_OPERATION_FAILED` is an error from the device. You should look into the device sdk or try with another one.

Comment: Hi Sylvain, I have built and tested the APK in two devices, one samsung galaxy tab 3, and one samsung galaxy S5. both devices showing same error.

Comment: Your documentation link points to the Web Services version of the Google Places API, but your code looks to be attempting to access the Android version of the Google Places API. Is your key for Web Services? You need to enable the Android version separately in the dev console.

Comment: I am still looking for the solution of this problem

Answer (score 0):

The AndroidManifest.xml should include permission :

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
```

and tag

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```